# VSCode, Ctrl+Tab does not quick switch editor windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

Strange problem appears on *one* of my machines.

Hit Ctrl+Tab, just hit and immediate release of Ctrl - should switch to the last used editor window. Should.
But instead I have a drop down with list of editors and have to press Enter to do the actual switch.

Holding Ctrl and hitting Tab several times - acts normal.

The problem I see is on VSCode v1.66.2. Another two machines have the very same version and do not experience that issue. So I am assuming the problem is somewhere in settings but I am at loss which one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, I had to write the question down to find the answer...

The reason for the problem was in extension. In this case it was "Keyboard Macro Beta". It overrides the default behavior of Ctrl+Tab, for some reason.

Found it by just typing "Ctrl+Tab" in the filter field of Keyboard Shortcuts.

Disable/uninstall the extension and default behavior for the hotkey was restored.